# mssql to mysql query conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The below query works fine in mssql.
I tried using information_schema instead of sys. But no luck in mysql.

```
            SELECT c.NAME AS property_name,
                   t.NAME AS datatype
            FROM   sys.columns c
            JOIN   sys.objects o
            ON     o.object_id = c.object_id
            JOIN   sys.types t
            ON     t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
            JOIN   sys.schemas s
            ON     o.schema_id = s.schema_id
            WHERE  s.NAME ='{0}'
            AND    o.NAME ='{1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME AS property_name,
    DATA_TYPE AS datatype
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = {0} AND
    TABLE_NAME = {1}
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Thanks lot for the help.